# List all EC2 instance types in a region or AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

While there appear to be a few ways to output and filter some AWSCLI commands into this list, does someone have a nice+easy way to list all EC2 instance types for a specific region?

Or perhaps that list is published in a .json file up in a bucket someplace, maintained by AWS?

I'm simply looking for this sort of output:

```
t1.micro
t2.nano
t2.micro
t2.small
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it seems that at least one programmatic way to do this is to query the AWS Pricing API:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json | jq -r '.products[].attributes["instanceType"]' | sort -u | grep '\.'
```

A gist for this is here, in case of future tweaks:
https://gist.github.com/nmagee/b096e6fadf9ac336da7ffdada43f656a

What this is lacking is grouping/specifying by AWS Region, which can be an important distinction -- not every region has all instance type offerings.

Comment: You can obtain [Regional price lists](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-regional-price-lists/) that might show instance types. However, it will **not** go down to the AZ level. When Regions add new AZs, the new AZs often do not support older-generation instance types.

Comment: I've created a more comprehensive solution that accounts for all current instance type offerings in all possible AZs. https://gist.github.com/mrsiesta/0e4fac21c0eb0e8977e1de7b5277e63b

Comment: Just a note: this document is now 614M, and probably not something you'll want to use as a reference in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

As Far As I Know, such list is not available and cannot be queried from aws cli.

Even when running the [`aws ec2 run-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html), the `instance-type` parameter lists available instance types and refers to [aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html)

[Others](http://www.ec2instances.info/) have parsed the data and made it available.

Comment: Thanks Frédéric. I have always liked that ec2instances.info page, and they note at the bottom that they are scraping this off of AWS web pages. Seems like something you should be able to grab in code though?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this is not something you can just get out of an AWS API endpoint.

So to fill this gap, I've built a general module for dealing with this issue.

I hope this helps for a variety of use cases:
https://gist.github.com/mrsiesta/0e4fac21c0eb0e8977e1de7b5277e63b