# Programmatic way [JAVA] to fetch the list of supported EC2 instance types in a particular availability zone

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am trying to fetch the list of supported instance types in a particular availability zone. I want to do that in my code using **Java**. One way to deal with it is by running the dry-run request for runInstance API and rely on the result. Wondering if there is any other way to do that. I see some answers here ([List all EC2 instance types in a region or AZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283036/list-all-ec2-instance-types-in-a-region-or-az)) on how to do it in command line, what I am looking for is how to do it in Java.